# Run sudo as another non-root user and save in this user's home directory

Tags: permissions, files, sudo

I added a new group: `ircuser` and a new user: `ircuser`

In `visudo` I placed this line:

```
myuser localhost=(ircuser) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/irssi
```

Created `ircuser` directory, where config files, caches, etc should be saved:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 ircuser ircuser 4096 Mar  2 10:28 ircuser
```

When issuing the command:

```
sudo -Hu ircuser /usr/bin/irssi
```

or

```
sudo -u ircuser /usr/bin/irssi
```

The program can't save the config file in the `ircuser` directory.

```
** ERROR **: Couldn't create /home/myuser/_web/ircuser/.irssi directory
aborting...
Aborted
```

But, it is being run as `ircuser`:

```
ps auxw | grep irssi
ircuser  11962  0.0  0.0  23684  2504 pts/6    S+   11:18   0:00 /usr/bin/irssi
```

So, albeit `irssi` is run by `ircuser` it can't write to a directory owned by the same user?
What do I need to change to allow it saving there?

Comment: Does `/home/myuser/_web/ircuser/` exists ? if yes, it belongs to ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem probably lies in not having eXecute permission in one of the parent directories leading up to ircuser's home directory.  In order for any user to traverse, not necessarily look into a directory, that user must have execute permission either via a group, or via other.  If you have these permissions:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 myuser myuser 4096 Mar  2 10:28 /home/myuser
```

And ircuser is not part of the myuser group, then ircuser can't access any file underneath even if it has permissions for that directory.  If you try this instead:

```
drwxrwx--x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Mar  2 10:28 /home/myuser
```

Then ircuser can't browse myuser's home directory, but it can potentially access some file beneath it such as `/home/myuser/_web/ircuser`

UPDATE: A few more details I left out from the above description.  Permissions are evaluated as you traverse the file system.  It's possible to be able to access a folder starting from the current directory that you can't access starting from the root directory.  If you change your working directory to somewhere else, you will loose your handle on the current directory and loose access to the files in it.  If you use something like sudo su - ircuser, su will switch to the home directory of ircuser before dropping root privileges.  At that point, you have a valid handle for ircuser's home directory because it's the current working directory.  If you start irssi, it will be running in ircuser's home directory as ircuser.  If you try to access .irssi, that will work because you have eXecute permission on the current direcory.  If you have to traverse a directory where you are lacking eXecute permission, iy will fail.  For example, opening up the file `/home/myuser/_web/ircuser/.irssi` or even starting from the current directory and using the relative path of `../../_web/ircuser/.irssi` because it requires traversing `/home/myuser` where you have no eXecute permission.

Comment: That's it! When I changed `ircuser` to `/home` the problem was solved. Thank you for the explanation. The only thing I don't understand now is (as I mentioned in a commento to pat) that the program (`lynx`in that case) appears in `ps auxw` as being run by `ircuser`, which is fine, but also by `root`. Would you mind explaining why does this happen? Is this a security risk?

Comment: @Luis I updated the description to better clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-H` option which makes the command executed with `sudo` to consider 'home' the user's home directory. You can find more detailed explanation on sudo's man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Comment: As you can see, it doen't work even when I use `-H` option.

Comment: What home directory is set for ircuser in `/etc/passwd`? That's the directory `sudo -H` will try to use. Also check in `/etc/sudoers` the values of env_reset, env_keep or always_set_home.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind trying with 
  sudo -iu ircuser /usr/bin/irssi ?

Additionally, as Patkos Csaba already stated check for the env_reset, env_keep Defaults set in your sudoers.

From the sudoers manpage:

```
As a special case, if sudo's -i option (initial login) is specified,
sudoers will initialize the environment regardless of the value of
env_reset.  The DISPLAY, PATH and TERM variables remain unchanged;
HOME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, and LOGNAME are set based on the target user.
On Linux and AIX systems the contents of /etc/environment are also
included.  All other environment variables are removed.
```

So sudo -i will initialize the environment getting around the values of these.

Edit: I've reproduced your setup on a Ubuntu box and even sudo -u ircuser /usr/bin/irssi works fine for me.

From my /etc/sudoers

```
<snipped>
Defaults    env_reset, log_output
<snipped>
testing LABUBU01=(ircuser) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/irssi
```

Versions:

```
testing@LABUBU01:~$ sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.3p1
pmplugin policy_plugin 5.6.0 (034)
pmplugin io_plugin 5.6.0 (034)
testing@LABUBU01:~$ uname -a
Linux LABUBU01 2.6.35-28-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:00:26 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux


testing@LABUBU01:~$ ls -lap /home/
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root     4096 2012-03-02 15:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 root     root     4096 2011-12-08 15:48 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 ircuser  ircuser  4096 2012-03-02 15:57 ircuser/
```

/EDIT

EDIT2:

your error:

> ** ERROR **: Couldn't create /home/myuser/_web/ircuser/.irssi directory
>   aborting...
>   Aborted

states, it cannot create /home/myuser/_web/ircuser/.irssi which is in your home, not in ircuser's home directory.
/EDIT2

Comment: I deleted `ircuser` and started again, this time not modifying user base directory `-b` option in `adduser`.  It works now. Thank you both. Problem (?) now is that `ps auxw | grep lynx` (changed irssi for lynx) gives:`root     15461  0.0  0.0  20064  1516 pts/0    S+   16:52   0:00 sudo -Hu ircuser /usr/bin/lynx
ircuser  15462  0.0  0.0  19544   456 pts/2    Ss   16:52   0:00 sudo -Hu ircuser /usr/bin/lynx
ircuser  15463  0.0  0.1  22788  5016 pts/2    S+   16:52   0:00 /usr/bin/lynx
ircuser  15464  0.0  0.0      0     0` as you can see a root owned `lynx`. Is this fine?